# How did drinking from the Mortal Cup give Simon back his memories?

Tags: shadowhunters, mortal-instruments

I can't remember if this was ever spelled out in the books, but why does drinking from the Mortal Cup give Simon back his memories? It seemed to me that it was just taken for granted that it would help, but why? What power does the Mortal Cup have to give back memories taken away by a demon?

Comment: When does drinking from the Mortal Cup give Simon back his memories? One of the episodes of the show?

Comment: In tales of Shadowhunter academy. Isabelle says "“Once you Ascend, you’ll get all your memories back!” Isabelle shouted at him." And then when he does ascend, he does get them all back.

Answer (score 0):

Simon needed to ascend, as it would counteract the spell that Asmodeus did, and return his memories. It also would ensure that they would be able to remain together, as Shadowhunters cannot marry Mundanes.

Comment: Do you have any evidence for this that this is indeed how it works that you could [edit] in?